# Where can I find a pistol silencer in the single player campaign?

Tags: crysis-2

How can you get a silencer for the M12 Nova and Feline?

I completed the game and during the whole playthough I only encountered one. During the mission "Lab Rat" where you are attacked by a Cell helicopter in Dr. Goulds lab, one enemy dropped a M12 Nova with a silencer. But I died and had to reload, and this time no enemy dropped one. During the rest of the game I examined (almost) every pistol or SMG dropped by enemies, but never found one with an attached silencer.

Is there some guaranteed opportunity to pick one up which I missed or at least one situation where one drops with a high propability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the mission "Sudden Impact", when you walk across a bridge a ceph drop ship comes and makes the bridge collapse. When you fell down, there is a parking garage down the street on the left.

In there you can find the pistol silencer.

If you have collected it, the pistol silencer is available for the M12 Nova, Hammer and Feline.

Unfortunately, there is a bug which can relock the gadget and it becomes unavailable again.